# What is the fastest data structure and/or algorithm to find an insert location in a sorted numerical list or array without actually inserting (in c#)

Tags: c#, performance, search, collections, insert

Basically, what's the fastest way to find the would-be insertion location for a number in an ordered list without actually doing the insertion?  The main concern is efficiency in tight loops.

I will have a list of anywhere between 1 and 100 float values, in most cases somewhere between 20 and 60, so for example, I have:

`{0, 1.5f,  10f, 15.6f, 100f}`

If I input the value 1.8f, I want to get the return value of 2.  If I input the value 20, I want to get the value 4, and if I input 500.2f, I want the value 5.

There are no guarantees as to the sparseness of the list members' values, but they are guaranteed to be ordered correctly.  The size of the data structure is not a factor,  only speed and minimal garbage collection.  So if a potential solution requires a larger data structure or for the individual components of the list to be some type of struct with additional information instead of a plain float, that's fine.

Comment: You can benchmark different approaches and choose the most appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm unless there's extra knowledge about the array of numbers (like range etc) you won't be able to do it faster then O(log n) with n the length of the array

Comment: BinarySearch by definition.

Comment: [binary search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.7.2) if it's an *"ordered list"*:

```
public static int GetInsertIndex<T>(List<T> list, T item)
{
    int nextHigherIndex = list.BinarySearch(item);
    return nextHigherIndex < 0 ? Math.Abs(nextHigherIndex) - 1 : nextHigherIndex + 1;
}
```

The rules of the returned value of `BinarySearch` are:

> The zero-based index of item in the sorted `List<T>` if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise
>   complement of the index of the next element that is larger than item
>   or, if there is no larger element, the bitwise complement of Count.

For example:

```
var list = new List<float>{0, 1.5f,  10f, 15.6f, 100f};
int insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(list, 1.8f);
```